# Page opened using jQuery load with wrong image paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, image

I have two pages:

one is http://local.host/orders/list.aspx and a
second one http://local.host/orders/provider/info.aspx

then I have http://local.host/themes/images/image.jpg

when I use jQuery.load() to load the second page within the first one, the image link is

"....\themes\images\image.jpg" instead of "..\themes\images\image.jpg".

I undestand that is because the second page runs on server and it is in the orders/provider folder but, is there any way to change the folder context on which response src links are calculated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know they are looked down upon, but why do you not use an iframe to host the second page inside the first page?

Comment: Project manager disapproves of IFrames

Comment: In your aspx pages, are you using site-relative paths, like  `~/themes/images/images.jpg`?

Comment: Yes I am. All paths are site relative.

Answer (score 0):

Made a jQuery script that fixes the issue.

```
function fixImgPaths() {
$.each($('#gridContent img'), function (index, value) {
    if ($(value).attr('oldsrc') == undefined) {
        $(value).attr('oldsrc', value.attributes.src.value);
    }
    $(value).attr('src', $(value).attr('oldsrc').substring(3));
});
```

}

This small script not only fixes the extra "../" issue of the path but can handle multiple calls without removing to many "../" from the path.

Not quite the solution, but it works.